# How to combine three SQL tables in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

I have 3 tables - Collections, Shipments, and Parcels.

**Question 1**

A collection has one to many shipments. A shipment may have one to many parcels per shipments.

```
Collections table
id
user_id

Shipments table
id
collections_id
shipment information(currently irrelevant)

Parcels table
id
shipment_id
parcelnumber
```

Show.blade

How can I display them in my blade view as follows?

[Blade view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDeLL.png)

**Question 2**

Create.blade

When a user adds a new Shipment, a collection should be created and the newly created shipment should be linked with the collection. How could I assign the newly created shipment to the collection?

I truly need advice on whether I should start over and change the database tables build

If any additional information is needed regarding to Models/Views/Controllers please let me know.

Collections Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Collections extends Model
{


public function Shipments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Shipments');
}

public function Parcels() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Parcels','App\Shipments');
}


}
```

Kind regards,

user3088327

Comment: For your first question:  [DB Join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins), then output to blade by [blade#displaying-data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: For question 2, you should make a select box for users to choose Collections, or [create new Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#inserts), Then you will get collection id by `$collection_id = $model->save()` to assign to your Shipment

Comment: Hello Ngoc Nam,

I would like to get the ID to which Collection I should assign the Shipment, it shouldn't be something a user has a possibility to edit.

Comment: there are 2 ways. **1**: get collection_id from current collection list (you can put this list in select box for user choosing, or by your own condition). **2**: create new `collection_id` by `$collection_model->save()` method (it can be inserted with empty data or your own data, upto you). **"How could I assign the newly created shipment to the collection?"** I do not know clear your condition to set Shipments.collection_id, but you can set this attribute, this collection_id must in Collection.id :D

Comment: That's perfect, I didnt know that You can get the id right after save(). 

Thanks a lot Ngoc Nam :).

Answer (score 0):

Try This Solution in Your Model

```
public function Shipments() {
    return $this->hasOne(App\Model\Shipments:class);
}

public function Parcels() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(App\Model\Parcels:class,App\Model\Shipments:class);
}
```

In blade

```
$comments = App\Model\Collection::find(1)->Shipments()->Parcels()->get();

foreach ($Shipments as $Shipment) {
    //
}
foreach ($Parcels as $Parcel) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for Your reply but when trying to use what You suggested I'm getting an error. 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::Parcels()

Answer (score 0):

Use another method with:("use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;")

```
$combine = DB::table('collections')
          ->JOIN('shipments','collections.id,'=',shipments.collection_id')
          ->JOIN('parcels','parcels.shipments_id','=','shipments.id')
           ->SelectRaw('combines.id as chipID, ...')
          ->get();
```

Or:
In model(shipments):

```
public function Shipments() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\collections'); //can add ->select(..)
}

public function Parcels() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Parcels');
}
```

In controller:

```
$collections= Shipments::with('shipments')->with('parcels')->get();
```

Comment: Hello,

Your query currently gives me the output of every parcel as a single line which is not the solution i'm looking for unfortunately. 

Please look at the image provided by me. 

Kind regards